# How to deploy Wordpress Multisite on Windows Azure, my way

Tags: azure, dns, wordpress

I am looking at the pricing calculator of Windows Azure. It tells me that my 20 Wordpress websites will cost: €132,77 p/month. (shared websites) So not a big deal.

When I researched the internet for solutions with Wordpress Multisite and Azure, I came across this page: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-wordpress-multisite-to-windows-azure-using-the-wordpress-scaffold

And from Stackoverflow this one: [How to install a Multi-Site Wordpress on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656670/how-to-install-a-multi-site-wordpress-on-windows-azure)

Both websites do not give me the solution I want, I explain:

The problem with the first URL is, it uses Hosted Service, Storage account and SQL Azure database. Not a big deal, because there are know problems with the latter. Also, with Websites I can choose Reserved and host to 100 websites on a reserved instance. But with this one I do not have experience, so I hope that if you have experience with it and join the discussion.

The last URL I gave, uses Wordpress Multisite with subfolders. What I want is to use Wordpress Multisite with each website his own domains, and own plugins and themes folders.

So to recap, I have two questions, yet separated from each other:
- Can I use Windows Azure to deploy Wordpress Multisite on it and have multiple domain names
- Can I use Wordpress Multisite to have each website its own directory with plugins and themes **and** have domain names pointing to them

I dont ask a total solution, just a hint to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is recent guidance using the Windows Azure "Web Sites" functionality:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/convert-wordpress-site-to-multisite/

Using the domain mapper plugin, it looks like it should provide the ability to use custom domain names for each network site, provided you followed the instructions to setup the proper A records in your DNS and configured them in the Azure management portal.

Comment: This page doesn't exist anymore